# run all Java class files in a folder

Tags: java

Is there a way to run all Java class files in a folder?

I'm looking for something similar to `javac sources/org/mysteryhobo/algorithms/*.java` but for running instead of compiling.

Comment: Your favorite shell probably has a way to loop through file lists and do stuff with them. Perhaps you should [edit] to make clear the constraints?

Comment: Are talking about running a program with all of the *.class files on the classpath, or are you talking about running all class files individually?

Comment: why would you want to do it?

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg, even then, what is the requirement? Usually one java file with main() method is run for stand alone applications. However, Web/Enterprise Applications work differently [different start point, not via main()]

Answer (score 0):

you can use apache ant tool.check for exec command or this link :

https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html

String[] args = new String[]{"-buildfile", "path to build.xml", targetName};
        org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(args);

build.xml can contain your targets

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a bash shell you could do something like this:

```
for x in $(ls -1 *.class | sed 's/.class//'); do; java $x; done
```